# Haskell ByteString / Data.Binary.Get question

Tags: haskell, bytestring

Attempting to use Data.Binary.Get and ByteString and not understanding what's happening. My code is below:

```
getSegmentParams :: Get (Int, L.ByteString)
getSegmentParams = do 
    seglen <- liftM fromIntegral getWord16be
    params <- getByteString (seglen - 2)
    return (seglen, params)
```

I get the following error against the third item of the return tuple, ie payload:

```
Couldn't match expected type `L.ByteString'
       against inferred type `bytestring-0.9.1.4:Data.ByteString.Internal.ByteString'
```

Someone please explain to me the interaction between Data.Binary.Get and ByteStrings and how I can do what I'm intending. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

It says you expect the second element of the tuple to be a `L.ByteString` (I assume that L is from `Data.ByteString.Lazy`) but the `getByteString` routine returns a strict ByteString from `Data.ByteString`.  You probably want to use `getLazyByteString`.

Answer (score 1):

There are two `ByteString` data types: one is in `Data.ByteString.Lazy` and one is in `Data.ByteString`.

Given the `L` qualifying your ByteString, I presume you want the lazy variety, but `getByteString` is giving you a strict `ByteString`.

Lazy `ByteString`s are internally represented by a list of strict `ByteString`s.

Fortunately `Data.ByteString.Lazy` gives you a mechanism for turning a list of strict `ByteString`s into a lazy `ByteString`.

If you define

```
import qualified Data.ByteString as S


strictToLazy :: S.ByteString -> L.ByteString
strictToLazy = L.fromChunks . return
```

you can change your code fragment to

```
getSegmentParams :: Get (Int, L.ByteString)
getSegmentParams = do 
    seglen <- liftM fromIntegral getWord16be
    params <- getByteString (seglen - 2)
    return (seglen, strictToLazy params)
```

and all should be right with the world.

Comment: You don't need to convert to a Lazy ByteString - just get one directly via `getLazyByteString`.  The haddock docs are great.

Comment: Quite true in this case.  It's worth noting this is a distinctly different operation.  Using `getByteString` when it isn't needed will force the entire `seglen` of bytes while `getLazyByteString` will remain lazy.  Perhaps this is unimportant when the maximum size is 64kB, but if that were a `getWord32be` then you'd likely want the lazy behavior instead of potentially forcing a 32GB allocation.